# How to Sort In-Memory XML with Microsoft XMLDOM?

Tags: xml, sorting, msxml

Besides using XSLT...

How to Sort In-Memory XML with Microsoft XMLDOM?

Comment: @Doug has a point... why can you not use XSLT ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with any method other than using XSLT to sort XML.

Why is XSLT not an option? It's simple and should not a performance buster. You can cache the FreeThreadedDOMDocument object once it has loaded the XSLT document to avoid parsing and compiling the XSLT document each time.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no way to sort in-memory XML without using XSLT to by moving the data to a new (sorted) list. You could copy the nodes to a sorted list, then put the nodes back in the new order. The exact technique depends a bit on your development software.